# How to delete specific files from the Source folder using delete task in Azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to add a task to delete files with specific type from source folder and all the sub folders using delete task in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Delete task: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops doesn't seem to provide any information on the patterns.

I have tried following combinations but none of them worked. 
*(.xyz)
(*.xyz)
*.xyz
*.xyz\

my expectation is to delete files with .xyz type from all the sub folders.

Comment: As a workaround I have started using powershell task and wrote custom script to handle this.

Comment: Hi, Do you try Ben's solution? Does it work ?

Comment: If Ben's answer helps you solve the problem,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you for the link!!, I was not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting:

`**/*.xyz`

As the Contents variable value.

The full range of pattern filters is described in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops#arguments).

Comment: Thanks, Ben. **/*.xyz is deleting .xyz files from all the subfolders.

Comment: @julinshah glad that its now working for you! Could you please mark this as the accepted answer if it has fixed your problem?

Comment: @BenSmith, I am using TFS 2018 & Delete Files Task, deleting all folder except the 2 ones, means i need to keep only 2 folders, what would be the pattern of only having the (bin) and (reports) folder

Comment: Do you already know it @SaadAwan?